# Docker Compose does not work: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose, fedora

So I try to run docker-compose on Fedora 36 but any time I try it, it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
return next(matches).load()
File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
module = import_module(match.group('module'))
File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'`
```

`

I tried using pip install docker-compose but It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

For RPM-based distros, run:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install docker-compose-plugin
```

Also, you will try to manually install with bin file:

```
curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.15.1/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I tried it and it didn't help. So I tried rebooting the computer and now I got just Segmentation fault error when trying to run docker-compose. Don't you have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: It's probably good to say that it crashes even when just checking a version

Answer (score -1):

Seems a python missing module. Try to install "compose".

```
sudo pip install compose
```

Or remove docker-compose from the system with pip and try to reinstall using the version supplied by the vendor

```
sudo yum install docker-compose
```

Also you can try to use docker-compose-plugin and use "docker compose" instead of "docker-compose". Try installing with package manager.

```
sudo yum install docker-compose-plugin
```

It should help. Tell me if helped.